# Is Qiskit transpile function (with basis_gates=['u', 'cx']) universal?

Tags: qiskit, universal-gates, transpile

It's well known that the single-qubit rotation gate $U(\theta, \phi, \lambda)$ and the controlled-not gate $CX_{i,j}$ form one of the **universal set of gates** for quantum computation. So here's my question: is the Qiskit [`transpile`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.transpile.html?highlight=transpile#qiskit.compiler.transpile) function able to compile any given quantum circuit by using `u` and `cx` gates only?

In particular, I would assume that the following code will always work with no errors:

```
from qiskit.circuit.random import random_circuit
from qiskit.compiler import transpile

qc = random_circuit(num_qubits=5, depth=10)
tqc = transpile(qc, basis_gates=['u', 'cx'])
```

Unfortunately, it would seem not to be so and I was wondering why. I also noticed that, if I add the identity gate `id` in the list of `basis_gates`, the transpilation looks to always run successfully and I'm not sure about the reason for this.

The error produced by qiskit is:

```
QiskitError: "Cannot unroll the circuit to the given basis, ['u', 'cx'].
Instruction id not found in equivalence library and no rule found to expand."
```

Comment: Do you get an error ? If so it would be helpful to see the traceback. Gates 'u' and 'cx' worked for me when I was transpiling.

Comment: Sometimes it works, others it raises an error. For instance, try `random_circuit(num_qubits=5, depth=10, seed=1)`: you should be able to reproduce the issue (I'm using Qiskit Terra version 0.22.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis gates `u`, `cx` are universal. This error is an artifact of the Qiskit transpiler. Change your transpiler call line to this:

```
tqc = transpile(qc, basis_gates=['u', 'cx', 'id'])
```

And the error should be fixed.

The reason this error occurs is because the identity gate (called `id`) can be used as a sort of timing enforcement gate for when the circuit is executing/or compiling. But, of course it is not actually needed in order to completely specify any intended quantum circuit. I assume in future versions of Qiskit this may be changed somehow so that users can be more selective for when they want to strictly include `id` gates or not.

By the way, this may actually be a bug in some cases (you should check this for your test cases), for example if `id` is not ever used by the transpiler for an example random circuit. In this case you should report this as a bug in the Qiskit Github.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your explanation about the `id` gate and why it should be in the basis set. But to me, it looks like a bug. +1 anyways.

Comment: I'm also trying to understand why this isn't a flat-out bug. If the transpiler needs "id" for internal purposes, then it can add them and then delete them.  What am I missing?

Comment: Thank you Elijah. I knew about the `id` gate as a "delay cycle" (see also [qiskit-terra issue#4671](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/7641)) but I'm still not sure that's the only explanation for this problem. Indeed, if it was, I would expect the same error raised for any quantum circuit; instead, if you try for example `random_circuit(num_qubits=5, depth=10, seed=2)` the transpiler does the job without complaining.

Comment: This is because `random_circuit(num_qubits=5, depth=10, seed=1)` returns a circuit contains `I`-gate, while `random_circuit(num_qubits=5, depth=10, seed=2)` don't. You can easily check this by drawing them: `random_circuit(num_qubits=5, depth=10, seed=1).draw('mpl')`.

Comment: Ah ok as easy as that. So, maybe, simply adding the equivalence $I = U(0, 0, 0)$ to the Qiskit [equivalence_library](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/main/qiskit/circuit/library/standard_gates/equivalence_library.py) should solve the problem.